# ImportError: No module named mosquitto

Tags: python, ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto on Ubuntu 15.10 using the following command

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

To check if Mosquitto is installed i type mosquitto and it shows all the details as follows:

```
1458716686: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Sun, 14 Feb 2016 15:48:26 +0000) starting
1458716686: Using default config.
1458716686: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1458716686: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

Which implies mosquitto is working right?

So i proceed with my program written in python. (Pyton version 2.7)

```
import mosquitto
mqttc = mosquitto.Mosquitto("python_pub")
mqttc.will_set("/event/dropped", "Sorry, I seem to have died.")
mqttc.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60, True)
mqttc.publish("hello/world", "Hello, World!")
```

On running the above program i get this error

```
ImportError: No module named mosquitto
```

I am new to the whole mqtt concept. Please let me know where i went wrong

Comment: Their website has [this](http://mosquitto.org/documentation/python/) to say about using in Python

Comment: The tech team is persistent on wanting to use mosquitto. How do I convince my tech team to use paho instead of mosquitto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mosquitto python module is no longer part of the Eclipse Mosquitto project, it has moved to the Eclipse Paho project instead.

You can install it with `pip install paho-mqtt` or `pip3 install paho-mqtt`.

You could then do:

```
import paho.mqtt as paho
mqttc = paho.Client()
...
```

The remainder of the API is largely the same, it has just been expanded and improved.

Comment: I used paho earlier to Mosquitto. And the program works in paho. But my tech lead is insisting on using Mosquitto as broker. I mentioned mosquito being donated to paho as well. Mosquitto is what they want to use. What do I do?

Comment: Mosquitto the project consists of a number of parts. There is the broker, a C and C++ client library and some client implementations. There used to be a Python wrapper to the C library, that then turned into the pure Python mosquitto.py. That code has moved to Eclipse Paho as I've explained. You can use mosquitto the broker and Paho Python client library together just fine.

Comment: Okay.. mosquito broker and paho client.. Got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/ says:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
client = mqtt.Client()
```

check another code